# Declaring a boolean method in java

Tags: java, methods

Sorry if this is a primitive topic, I have a professor that doesn't speak english and I'm rather lost.

I'm trying to declare a method that checks if a triangle is equilateral. It keeps telling me that I'm comparing a boolean to an int in my if statement. side1, side2, and side3 are all int types.

```
public boolean is_equilateral(){
    if (side1 == side2 == side3){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

Comment: `"Sorry if this is a primitive topic, ..."` -- It's only a primitive topic because your method returns `boolean` and not `Boolean`.

Comment: The result of one `==` comparison is a boolean.

Comment: The fact that your professor does not speak English really sounds like something you should talk to your university about.

Comment: `return (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3);`  You don't need the `if` statement.

Comment: Try to stick to Java naming conventions too such as `isEquilateral()` instead of `is_equilateral()`

Answer (score 6):

In your comparison `if (side1 == side2 == side3)`
it will first compare `side1 == side2`, resulting in a boolean.

Afterwards it will compare the first result (`boolean`) with the last element (`int`), thus giving an error.
You can't compare a `boolean` to an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `side1 == side2` evaluates to boolean, thus you cannot compare it to another int. But you can do:

```
if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3)) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
side1 == side2 && side1 == side3
```

instead.

Comment: This was right! It makes sense now too. It was reading "side1 == side2"" as a boolean in itself and comparing that to side3. Thank you!

Comment: @TaylorDavison It's not "reading" `side1 == side2` as a `boolean`.  It's comparing `side1` and `side2` via the `==` operator, which is a `boolean`.  Then it's comparing a `boolean` to `side3` with the `==` operator and returning that `boolean` to evaluate the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use

if((side1 == side2) && (side2 == side3))

instead of

if(side1 == side2 == side3)